# Is there any parameter space of Cramér–Rao_bound

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, statistics, soft-question, definition

It is known that Cramér–Rao_bound is the lower bound of variance of a parameter. A useful link is  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound There is also a term called 'superefficient', mentioned in the link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodges%27_estimator which claims that:  "In general, any superefficient estimator may surpass a regular estimator at most on a set of Lebesgue measure zero". My question is how "Lebesgue measure zero" is associated with the parameters discussed in the Cramér–Rao_bound? Is there a limitation where Cramér–Rao_bound is applicable?